# My POST request works on Postman but not with axios

Tags: axios, nuxt.js, mailchimp, netlify, aws-serverless

I have a nuxt project deployed on Netlify and now I want to add a newsletter (add a subscriber to my audience on Mailchimp). To achieve that, I've opted to use the AWS serverless lambda functions. To be honest, it's the first time that i've heard about serverless functions. I found this tutorial https://hashinteractive.com/blog/nuxt-js-mailchimp-integration-add-contact-to-list/ and at the end, i've decided to make a test on Postman. I've made a post to http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/subscribe and it worked. But when I try the same thing with axios I get the error 405 (method not allowed).

Newsletter.vue

```
      <form @submit.prevent='submitNewsletter' class="newsletter__form" >
            <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="newsletter__form-input" v-model="email">
            <button class="newsletter__form-button" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            email: ''
        }
    },
    methods:{
        
        submitNewsletter(){
            
            axios.post('http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/subscribe', { email: this.email}, {
                headers: {
                    methods: 'POST',
                    'Content-Type':'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }).
            catch((error) =>{
                console.log('The error:' + error)
            })
            
            this.$toasted.success("Thank you for your subscription !!!", { 
                theme: "toasted-primary", 
                position: "top-left", 
                containerClass: 'myContainer',
                fitToScreen: true,
                fullWidth: true,
                duration : 5000
            });  
        
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

functions > subscribe > subscribe.js

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch'); 
const base64 = require('base-64'); 


exports.handler = async (event, context) => { 
  // Only allow POST
  if (event.httpMethod !== 'POST') { 
    return { statusCode: 405, body: 'Method Not Allowed' };
  }
  const errorGen = msg => {
    return { statusCode: 500, body: msg }; 
  }; 
  try { 
    const { email } = JSON.parse(event.body);
    console.log(email);
    if (!email) { 
      return errorGen('Missing Email');
    } 
    const subscriber = { 
      email_address: email, 
      status: 'subscribed', 
    }; 

    console.log(subscriber);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(subscriber));

    const creds = `blooming-thoughts:${process.env.MAILCHIMPS_API_KEY}`;
    const response = await fetch(`https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/${process.env.AUDIENCE_ID}/members/`, { 
      method: 'POST', 
      headers: { 
        Accept: '*/*', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        Authorization: `Basic ${base64.encode(creds)}`, }, 
      body: JSON.stringify(subscriber), 
     
    }); 
    const data = await response.json();
    
    if (!response.ok) { 
      // NOT res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300 
      return { statusCode: data.status, body: data.detail }; 
    }
    return { 
      statusCode: 200, 
      body: JSON.stringify({ msg: "You've signed up to the mailing list!", detail: data, }), 
    }; 
  } catch (err) { 
    console.log(err); // output to netlify function log 
    return { 
      statusCode: 500, 
      body: JSON.stringify({ msg: err.message }),
    };
  } 
};
```

My netlify.toml

```
[build]
publish = "dist"
functions = 'functions'
```

I've made a push to my repository and netlify built without any error, but when I try to add a newsletter from my site nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem. If you're having trouble like I was, follow these steps:

1. Create a folder called functions in your root directory, then create a index.js (the file name is up to you).
2. Create a file called netlify.toml and add the following code :

   [build]
   functions = "functions"
3. Then, inside your index.js goes the code that will communicate with your API
4. On the vue component, make a post request to the `<your-site>`/.netlify/functions/index . You can find the endpoint going to functions on netlify dashbord.

Don't forget to register your env variables on Netlify (Build & Deploy) and that's it.